# Почему возникает ошибка Value Error, когда я ввожу целое число?

Tags: python

Я ввожу "74", а программа выдаёт ошибку:

```
s = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: @Андрюха автор написал, что ввёл "74"

Comment: Вы число вводите с кавычками или без?